# Split polygon features at specified point

Tags: arcgis-pro, splitting

I have three layers: points, lines, polygons. Each polygon feature contains one centroid point inside the polygon. I'd like to split each polygon with a line running through its respective centroid point AND that's parallel to its street centerline (purple dotted lines in the image). The result would be a theoretical front yard/back yard for each parcel polygon. Not sure what tool(s) to use and if the workflow could be automated? I have thousands of features so doing this manually with the edit tools isn't an option for me.[image: Parcels split by a line running through centroids]

Answer (score 1):

Possible algorithm based on working with **individual** parcel.

- Find distance from point to road, buffer entire road by this distance
- Intersect buffer with road and append result to initially empty dataset

So first run Near tool between all points and roads:

[image]

and do your iterations:

[image]

It might work at intersections and cul-de-sac, but I'd shuffle through results afterwards, because weird things happen.
[image]

I'd do it in Python, but model will do as well.

Comment: Thank you Felix. Running the Near tool first is what I was missing for capturing distance from centroids to the nearest road.